# Failed to decode downloaded font - deployed app

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, deployment, fonts, font-face

Currently I'm importing my custom font as follows in my css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Dinbek Light';
    src: url('./fonts/DINbek-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine locally. After I deploy the app onto AWS though, I see the following error in the console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://my-domain.elasticbeanstalk.com/fonts/DINbek-Light.ttf
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I've scoured over other resources but am unable to come up with a solution. Note that I'm using Grunt to build the app, and the font file path is recognized as shown in the Resources tab:

[image]

It's just that the font style defaults to Times New Roman. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What build tools are you using? What is the process?